# weird compile-time error on Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, syntax-error, compile-time

code in xcode 4.2

Game Model.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Game_Model : NSObject{
    NSString  *playerName;
    int play;
    int won;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *playerName;
@property (nonatomic,readonly,assign) int play;
@property (nonatomic,readonly,assign) int won;
@end
```

Game Model.m

```
#import "Game Model.h"

@implementation Game_Model
@synthesize playerName,play,won;

+(NSString *)description{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@. Player:%@. Score: %d/%d",[super description],self.playerName,self.won,self.play];
}
@end
```

I made exactly (or nearly exactly) as in a book, but I got error messages:

- implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'struct objc_class
  *' is disallowed with ARC
- member reference type 'struct objc_class *' is a pointer; maybe you meant to use '->'?
- incomplete definition of type 'struct objc_class' Automatic Reference Counting Issue:
- Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'struct objc_class
  *' is disallowed with ARC
  I simply have no idea about these errors!
  Please help me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`description` is not a class method, but an instance method. What you create is a class method: `+(NSString*)description;`. You should not try to access instance properties (ivars) in a class method. Change `+` into `-`. Good luck!

Comment: That was exactly the problem! What I wanted to do was just overriding that method. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to refer to this

```
[super description]
```

and this might mess things around a little bit, try a return without that and see what happens

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Player:%@. Score: %d/%d",self.playerName,self.won,self.play];
```

Comment: I didn,t found this post useful because I solved all my problems by the previous post, but thank you anyway!